# how to get the value from complex array

Tags: arrays, wordpress

how to get the value of the keys like `user_login` ,`email` in this array

I tried all like `foreach`, `array keys`, `array['user_login']` but did not get the values.

I am working in wordpress. `print_r` prints the array data like this way

```
$array=$_SESSION;
print_r($array);
```

> Array ( [userdata] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object (
>   [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => WP_User [data] => stdClass Object (
>   [ID] => 1 [user_login] => admin [user_pass] =>
>   $P$BZzVW3B4g2f6pgocN3iu9h4J0CFmCj1 [user_nicename] => admin
>   [user_email] => abc@gmail.com [user_url] => [user_registered] =>
>   2013-05-22 02:21:09 [user_activation_key] => [user_status] => 0
>   [display_name] => admin ) [ID] => 1 [caps] => Array ( [administrator]
>   => 1 ) [cap_key] => wp_capabilities [roles] => Array ( [0] => administrator ) [allcaps] => Array ( [switch_themes] => 1
>   [edit_themes] => 1 [activate_plugins] => 1 [edit_plugins] => 1
>   [edit_users] => 1 [edit_files] => 1 [manage_options] => 1
>   [moderate_comments] => 1 [manage_categories] => 1 [manage_links] => 1
>   [upload_files] => 1 [import] => 1 [unfiltered_html] => 1 [edit_posts]
>   => 1 [edit_others_posts] => 1 [edit_published_posts] => 1 [publish_posts] => 1 [edit_pages] => 1 [read] => 1 [level_10] => 1
>   [level_9] => 1 [level_8] => 1 [level_7] => 1 [level_6] => 1 [level_5]
>   => 1 [level_4] => 1 [level_3] => 1 [level_2] => 1 [level_1] => 1 [level_0] => 1 [edit_others_pages] => 1 [edit_published_pages] => 1
>   [publish_pages] => 1 [delete_pages] => 1 [delete_others_pages] => 1
>   [delete_published_pages] => 1 [delete_posts] => 1
>   [delete_others_posts] => 1 [delete_published_posts] => 1
>   [delete_private_posts] => 1 [edit_private_posts] => 1
>   [read_private_posts] => 1 [delete_private_pages] => 1
>   [edit_private_pages] => 1 [read_private_pages] => 1 [delete_users] =>
>   1 [create_users] => 1 [unfiltered_upload] => 1 [edit_dashboard] => 1
>   [update_plugins] => 1 [delete_plugins] => 1 [install_plugins] => 1
>   [update_themes] => 1 [install_themes] => 1 [update_core] => 1
>   [list_users] => 1 [remove_users] => 1 [add_users] => 1 [promote_users]
>   => 1 [edit_theme_options] => 1 [delete_themes] => 1 [export] => 1 [simple_tags] => 1 [admin_simple_tags] => 1 [administrator] => 1 )
>   [filter] => ) )

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
$_SESSION>userdata('user_login');
```

To retrieve your user_login?

Comment: ,yes i tries but it gives Fatal error: Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object